# Disable mic-paren in the minibuffer (or at least in ido)

Tags: balanced-parentheses

I'm replacing a buggy code that was suppose to show a matching brace in the minibuffer in case it was off-screen with the following:

```
(paren-activate) ;; activates mic-paren
(setq paren-match-face 'highlight)
(setq paren-sexp-mode t)
(setq paren-highlight-offscreen t)
```

This works almost perfectly. The only problem, it highlights the matching braces also in the minibuffer when ido shows its thing.

How can I disable mic-paren in the minibuffer?

---

For reference, here is the old code snippet:

```
(show-paren-mode t)
(setq show-paren-style 'expression)
;; Show in the mini-buffer the matching brace in case it is off screen.
(defadvice show-paren-function
  (after show-matching-paren-offscreen activate)
  "If the matching paren is offscreen, show the matching line in the
        echo area. Has no effect if the character before point is not of
        the syntax class ')'."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (minibuffer-prompt))
      (let ((matching-text nil))
        ;; Only call `blink-matching-open' if the character before point
        ;; is a close parentheses type character. Otherwise, there's not
        ;; really any point, and `blink-matching-open' would just echo
        ;; "Mismatched parentheses", which gets really annoying.
        (if (char-equal (char-syntax (char-before (point))) ?\))
            (setq matching-text (blink-matching-open)))
        (if (not (null matching-text))
            (message matching-text)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to code to disable `mic-paren` in minibuffer whenever ido is used (using `ido-minibuffer-setup-hook`). Technically this does not disable `mic-paren` but sets its face to `nil` so that its highlighting does not have any effect

```
(defun my-remove-mic-paren-face-in-minibuffer ()
  (set (make-variable-buffer-local 'paren-match-face) nil))

(add-hook 'ido-minibuffer-setup-hook #'my-remove-mic-paren-face-in-minibuffer)
```

Also emacs already has a mode for highlighting matching parens `show-paren`, which is pretty [sophisticated](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/12/31/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-smarter-show-paren-mode/), you might want to try it out

Comment: I had issues enabling showing the match in the minibuffer using `show-paren`. That's why I decided to switch to `mic-paren`.

Comment: This works almost fine. If I hit `~/`, to jump to my home, then the bad facing re-appear in the minibuffer. Any solution?

Comment: I have edited the answer now it should work even when you enter `~/`